# AddEvent na tabela

Tags: php, html, calendar

Tenho o script abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addevent.com/libs/atc/1.6.1/atc.min.js" async defer></script>
<div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
    <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
    <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
    <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
    <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
    <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
</div>
```

Gostaria de colocá-lo em uma tabela html, mas quando coloco só aparece o botão sem funcionar

```
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
              Add to Calendar
              <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
              <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
              <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
              <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
              <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
              <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
              <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
              <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>
           <div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
              Add to Calendar
              <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
              <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
              <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
              <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
              <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
              <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
              <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
              <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr> 
    </table>
```

Estou tentando colocar em cada linha da tabela um botão, caso tenha mais de um

Só que eu quero pegar do php

```
 echo  "<tr>
            <td>
               <div title=\"Add to Calendar\" class=\"addeventatc\">
                  Add to Calendar
                  <span class=\"start\">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
                  <span class=\"end\">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
                  <span class=\"timezone\">America/Caracas</span>
                  <span class=\"title\">Summary of the event</span>
                  <span class=\"description\">Description of the event</span>
                  <span class=\"location\">Location of the event</span>
                  <span class=\"date_format\">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
                  <span class=\"client\">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
                </div>
            </td>
         </tr> ";
```

Referência: https://www.addevent.com/buttons/add-to-calendar#

Comment: Qual a sua concepção de "funcionar"? Eu testei com o código da tabela que você colocou (adicionando a tag `script`) e os botões e menu dropdown apareceram normalmente e até geraram o arquivo para o calendário do `iOS`

Comment: no meu, gerou só o botão, mas quando eu clico nao acontece nada

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Com o `script` de importação funcionando corretamente abaixo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addevent.com/libs/atc/1.6.1/atc.min.js" async defer></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
          Add to Calendar
          <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
          <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
          <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
          <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
          <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
          <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
          <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
          <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
          Add to Calendar
          <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
          <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
          <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
          <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
          <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
          <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
          <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
          <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: só que eu estou tentando rodar pelo php

Comment: acho que ele nao funciona com o php